# How to make GWT RichTextArea transparent under Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, gwt

By default GWT RichTextArea is transparent against the body background etc, this is true for Firefox, Chrome and Safari. But for Internet Explorer, it is not. Changing the css for like background-color etc doesn't seems to help, it is still giving me a white background within RichTextArea.

Need your assistance, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the RichTextArea component uses iframe element - it's body should have style background-color set to "transparent". The iframe element itself should have allowtransparency attribute set to "true".